# Best way to pass a huge xml parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

Actually I m trying to pass a huge `Xml` to my stored procedure, but I always get an out `of memory exception`, cause I m trying to pass a `string` which has a limit size to 2G. So is there how to to such a thing.

Comment: Have you tried using **XML** datatype in your SP parameter ?

Comment: How big are we talking?

Comment: @AlexK. well my file is in order to 116 Mb but, after I loaded it using XmlDocument and i try to get it's string to pass it as parameter i get an exception of out of memory

Comment: @KrishnrajRana well i tried to use the type SqlXml

Comment: Can you load the xml into a staging table and then reference a staging table ID as the parameter for the SP?

Comment: Just load it as a string, you cannot pass a XmlDocument as parameter

Comment: Well when I load it as string it handels the exception

Comment: Might be worth breaking it into chunks (maybe 100K each or so), uploading one at a time into a temporary location, then re-combining those chunks once they're all on the server. That way you're never dealing with any large communication, and never need a large string in memory in your .NET code. SQL Server should be able to easily re-combine those on its end.

Comment: @JoeEnos do you plz a tuto or an exmaple on how to do such a thing

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `XmlDocument` - it will take about 10x the amount of memory as your source document to load the DOM fully into memory.

Use `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`, or `XDocument` if you need to do manipulation of the document before passing it to SQL.  These will work because they will do streaming processing (particularly XmlReader/XmlWriter, which are heavily optimized for forward-only reading of XML data), instead of trying to load the entire document and its DOM all at once (like XmlDocument).

Load well formed XML from a file:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlParameterName", SqlDbType.Xml)
{
    Value = new SqlXml(XmlReader.Create("C:\\path\\to\\file.xml"));
});
```

Load from XML Data in a stream

```
Stream s;
// XML is in this stream
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlParameterName", SqlDbType.Xml)
{
    Value = new SqlXml(XmlReader.Create(s));
});
```

Load from an XDocument:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load/.Parse/etc....
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlParameterName", SqlDbType.Xml)
{
    Value = new SqlXml(xd.Root.CreateReader());
});
```

Comment: No i dont need to do any modificationto the document, my only request is how to pass the content of this document to my stored procedure, Please if you could tell me how to use the xmlreader to achiecve what i need

Comment: Updated to add some examples.

Comment: I tried all the examples you gave but I always get the same error, plz take a look at this image http://s2.postimg.org/75oink4i1/Capture.png

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: It's 116777 Ko and it contains 2112000 line

Comment: Try loading it into an XmlReader using just XmlReader.Create(uri).  XmlReader should be able to easily handle a 116mb file...

Comment: Well after loading it into xmlReader how can I send it to my sproc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74737/discussion-between-dan-field-and-moez-rebai).

Comment: I believe that it would be worth to add an example of how the passed xml can be used on the stored procedure side. I can not figure this out. I am trying to use the `xml` SQL data type, but it seems to always be empty.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using StringBuilder
[reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder)

Comment: Well even when you use the string builder it will need to convert it to string then y will face the same exception

Comment: This is on the right track, but needs a bit more.  @MoezRebai, it will be different because XmlDocument creates an in memory DOM structure to describe the document.