# Read an XML passed as an instance of an XmlReader on the stored procedure side

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, debugging, stored-procedures

How could I read an XML passed as an instance of an XmlReader on the stored procedure side?

I am following the [answer`s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516184/best-way-to-pass-a-huge-xml-parameter-to-stored-procedure).

Here is what I am doing on the C# side:

```
this.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
        "EXECUTE dbo.LegalContractorsDataSynchronize @data, @hashKey, @hash",
        new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Xml)
        {
            Value = new SqlXml(value)
        },
        new SqlParameter("@hashKey", hashKey),
        new SqlParameter("@hash", hash)
    );
```

Here is what I am doing in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LegalContractorsDataSynchronize] 
    (@data xml,
     @hashKey nvarchar(100),
     @hash nvarchar(2048))
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    MERGE [dbo].[LegalContractors] AS TblTarget
    USING (SELECT 
               [Code] = c.value('EDRPOU[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
               [ShortName] = c.value('SHORT_NAME[1]', 'nvarchar(512)'),
               [Name] = c.value('NAME[1]', 'nvarchar(2048)'),
               [LegalAddress] = c.value('ADDRESS[1]', 'nvarchar(2048)'),
               [Status] = c.value('STAN[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')       
           FROM 
               @data.nodes('/RECORD') AS T(c)) AS TblSource([Code], [ShortName], [Name], [LegalAddress], [Status])
        ON (TblSource.Code = TblTarget.Code AND TblSource.[Status] = TblTarget.[Status])

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
            INSERT ([Code], [ShortName], [Name], [LegalAddress], [Status]) 
            VALUES (TblSource.[Code], TblSource.[ShortName], TblSource.[Name], TblSource.[LegalAddress], TblSource.[Status])

        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET 
                TblTarget.[Code] = TblSource.[Code],
                TblTarget.[ShortName] = TblSource.[ShortName],
                TblTarget.[Name] = TblSource.[Name],
                TblTarget.[LegalAddress] = TblSource.[LegalAddress],
                TblTarget.[Status] = TblSource.[Status]

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
            DELETE;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [StorageCaches] WHERE S_Key = @hashKey)
        UPDATE [StorageCaches] 
        SET [S_Value] = @hash 
        WHERE S_Key = @hashKey
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO [StorageCaches] ([S_Key], [S_Value], [TenantId]) 
        VALUES (@hashKey, @hash, 1);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

While the hash is updated as expected, the entities are still not updated. So, maybe it have something to do with the handling of the xml on the stored procedureside?

Here is the sample xml I am using to verify my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DATA FORMAT_VERSION="1.0">
    <RECORD>
        <NAME>МІЖНАРОДНА ГРОМАДСЬКА ОРГАНІЗАЦІЯ МІЖНАРОДНА АКАДЕМІЯ БІОЕНЕРГОТЕХНОЛОГІЙ</NAME>
        <SHORT_NAME>МАБЕТ</SHORT_NAME>
        <EDRPOU>00011601</EDRPOU>
        <ADDRESS>01001, м.Київ, Шевченківський район, ВУЛИЦЯ ПРОРІЗНА, будинок 8, офіс 426</ADDRESS>
        <BOSS>ТКАЧЕНКО ВОЛОДИМИР АНДРІЙОВИЧ</BOSS>
        <KVED>94.12 Діяльність професійних громадських організацій</KVED>
        <STAN>зареєстровано</STAN>
        <FOUNDERS>
            <FOUNDER>Члени організації, розмір внеску до статутного фонду - 0.00 грн.</FOUNDER>
        </FOUNDERS>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <NAME>фоо</NAME>
        <SHORT_NAME>фоо короткое имя</SHORT_NAME>
        <EDRPOU>47474747</EDRPOU>
        <ADDRESS>фоо адрес</ADDRESS>
        <BOSS>фоо бос</BOSS>
        <KVED>фоо квед</KVED>
        <STAN>фоо состояние</STAN>
        <FOUNDERS>
            <FOUNDER>фоо организатор</FOUNDER>
        </FOUNDERS>
    </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

Also, I tried to debug my stored procedure. I followed the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262244/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-from-a-c-sharp-debug-session) question. I checked the `Enable SQL Server debugging` for the project which calls in it`s C# the SP. Also, I found the stored procedure in the SQL Server Object Explorer and checked the both Application Debugging and Allow SQL/CLR Debugging, but still the breakpoint in the stored procedure is disabled and when I hover over it, it tells me:

> The breakpoint will currently not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

[image]

I.e. in order to fix the issue, I need either a different way of handling the xml on the stored procedure side, or a way to enable the debugging in Visual Studio (also I has the SQL Server Management Studio, I tried to debug the call to SP as well, but with no success and I believe that it is a lot easier to do it in Visual Studio directly), or something else (I am not aware about, but you may recommend).

The issues in a nutshell: when I try to insert the sample data with the procedure presented above the data is not inserted (the respective table remains empty).

Comment: Why send XML to the server instead of just filling a table-valued parameter and sending it? Or insert the data into a staging table with SqlBulkCopy, then MERGE the staging and target tables? XML is not an answer to large data transfers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am not aware of the `table-valued` parameter. Could you, please, elaborate it?

Comment: You have to start at the root value when using `nodes`, i.e. `@data.nodes('/DATA/RECORD')` instead of `@data.nodes('/RECORD')`. Although I 100% agree that [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) are a much better solution to this problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in my case there is a third party service, the service serves the data in an xml file. The xml  file (when unzipped) has a greater than 1GB size. Do you think there are better ways to update my database according to the records in the file? Also, the server which fetches the file from a thrid party service and the DB server are the two different servers in my case.

Comment: @GarethD, thank you a lot. The `@data.nodes('/DATA/RECORD')` works. I am going to check the `table-valued parameters` and get back to you.

Comment: If you use SQL Server, you can use an SSIS package with an XML file source. On the client, you can read the file and use SqlBulkCopy to store the data in a staging table with minimal logging. Even with the current stored procudure, it's a *lot* easier and probably faster to insert the data into a staging table and merge afterwars. The current operation has no way of indexing the XML data so the JOIN will be *very* slow.

Comment: @GarethD, will the `table-value parameters` work if I have an xml file from the beginning?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, would it be time consuming for you to provide a little bit of code samples of what you are talking about, please?

Comment: There's typically no compelling reason to switch from XML to a table-valued parameter.

Comment: I concur, there is no need to switch from XML to a table-valued parameter.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, how would you recommend to send an XML which is 1 - 1.5GB in size to a DB?

Comment: If it's landing as rows and columns, client-side parsing and SqlBulkCopy or similar.  Table-Valued Parameters are also not for large bulk loads.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I was able to find only the examples of copying values from one table to another with the help of the [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8). Could you, please, provide an example in which an XML would be used instead of a table as a source?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, also I am not sure how could I mimic the MERGE with the SqlBulkCopy. It seems that the SqlBulkCopy can be used only for insert.

Comment: You can bulk load a staging table or temp table before running MERGE.  Or if you can break the input into reasonable chunks continue to use XML/TVP/JSON to send batches to load in a MERGE.